# The problem of openGauss database connection schema

Tags: open-gauss

we encountered a problem when migrating the database from oracle to guassdb. It is a compatible version with postgresdb, which uses schema,

For example, `select * from table1`

Now because gauss uses schema, our table is in a01

The query becomes `select * from a01.table1`, which causes all the codes to be changed during the migration. The schema is added to the front of each table name, which is too big. Is there a better solution, such as adding schema to the url connection, because we only use one schema for each project

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the user's search_path in the openGauss database. This parameter can also be configured through the url parameter in the jdbc.
for example: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=a1